# Special character (!, exclamation mark) in DB2 user password gives error when starting i2 Analyze or connecting from DB2 command console

Tags: passwords, db2

The following error occurs when starting i2 Analyze with example deployment 
(some parts of error messages are in Finnish because of the Windows localization settings, sorry about that)

```
setup -t startLiberty

java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.17.29] On ilmennyt yhteyden käyttöoikeusvirhe.  Syy: Käyttäjätunnus tai tunnussana ei kelpaa. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28000, Error Code = -4 214
```

I believe the error is more closely related to DB2(10.5 FP7) & Windows(W12R2) than i2 Analyze itself because when connecting from DB2 command console (db2cmd) and giving both username and password (with !) within a single line:

```
connect to WRITESTORE user db2admin using <SomePasswordWith!>
```

The error shown in console is as follows:

```
SQL0104N  Järjestelmä on löytänyt merkkijonoa "<tunnus>" seuraavan
tunnistamattoman sanakkeen "!".  Odotettuja sanakkeita ovat esimerkiksi
seuraavat: "NEW".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Anyhow, if password (with character !) is given only when prompted eg:

```
connect to WRITESTORE user db2admin
```

and giving password when asked, user is logged in without an error.
Also when connecting to DB2 with IBM DataStudio gives no error.

So, using passwords without special characters is a workaround for the issue.

Comment: And the question is ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21303153

Username/password with special characters need to be quoted when using them through CLP within db2prompt

Lainausmerkkeihin :)

```
connect to WRITESTORE user db2admin using '<SomePasswordWith!>'
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What works is: `set +H; db2 connect to DB user username using "'password!'"` That is: surround the pwd with single quotes **and** double quotes. The `set +H` disables bash's history expansion.